# How to count coefficient of variation value for each cluster ? - PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have data in my database table :

```
id  | Name  | Total | Cluster
1   | Alpha | 6025  |   C1
2   | Beta  | 5930  |   C1
3   | Car   | 4550  |   C1
4   | Delta | 5694  |   C1
5   | Echo  | 2500  |   C2
6   | Fuji  | 2850  |   C2
7   | Go    | 3150  |   C2
8   | Hero  | 3750  |   C2
9   | Icon  | 1850  |   C3
10  | Joy   | 1350  |   C3
11  | Kick  | 1455  |   C3
```

for example in my database have 3 cluster (C1,C2,C3) :

```
=AVERAGE(6025+5930+4550+5690) //result 5549,75
=STDEV(6025+5930+4550+5690)   //result 680,8722
CV for C1 = 680,8722 / 5549,75 //result 0,122685
CV for C2 = 529,7405 / 3062,5 //result 0,172976
etc..
```

How can i count the Coefficient Of Variation (CV) of each Cluster in PHP?

if there are 4 or more cluster in my database, how can i loop it for count CV?

Comment: *"if there are 4 or more cluster in my database, how can i loop it for count CV?"* Are you asking how `GROUP BY` works? -> `GROUP BY Cluster` ?? ...

Comment: You can use [`AVG()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg), [`STD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_std) *(not sure about this, it's for computing the standard deviation I think)*, and [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) to get values you needed

Comment: to add to @CarlBinalla as a large amount off poeple write invalid SQL with `GROUP BY` here , be sure to read [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) and avoid making that mistake..

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be done in this way:

```
$sql = 'SELECT cluster, (STDDEV(Total)/AVG(Total)) as CV FROM your_table GROUP BY cluster';
foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
    echo $row['cluster'] . ': ' . $row['CV'] . PHP_EOL;
}
```